# PHP Type Error with Cached Plugin definitions in DiscoveryCachedTrait.php

Tags: 8, caching, plugins

We have the following set up for Drupal 8.6.3 - IIS Server, MSSQL Server, [sqlsrv](https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv) drivers. However, every few hours, Drupal throws PHP errors(all of them belonging to the same kind) and most pages from the application become inaccessible. The error message is very long so I pasted the first 7 lines below. It doesn't depend on what plugin is being requested. The error is always raised at **Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager::doGetDefinition()**. Once we clear caches using **drush cr** the page becomes accessible again.

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager::doGetDefinition() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in 
E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DiscoveryCachedTrait.php on line 25 in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 43 of E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DiscoveryTrait.php) 

#0 E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DiscoveryCachedTrait.php(25): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition(false, 'views_query', true) 
#1 E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory.php(16): Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinition('views_query') 
#2 E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase.php(83): Drupal\Core\Plugin\Factory\ContainerFactory->createInstance('views_query', Array) 
#3 E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\modules\views\src\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase.php(817): Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginManagerBase->createInstance('views_query') 
#4 E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\modules\views\src\ViewExecutable.php(1182): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->getPlugin('query') 
#5 E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\modules\views\src\ViewExecutable.php(1222): Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->initQuery() 
#6 E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\modules\views\src\Plugin\views\display\PathPluginBase.php(390): Drupal\views\ViewExecutable->build() 
#7 E:\IISRoot\drupal-app\core\modules\views\src\Plugin\views\display\Page.php(180): Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\PathPluginBase->execute()
```

I went through the **DiscoveryCachedTrait.php** file where the error is being raised. It has the **$definitions** variable which has the cached definitions. If this variable is not set, the method **getDefinitions()** is being called. Ultimately, **$definitions** is being passed to the method **doGetDefinition()**. This method expects **$definitions** to be an array, but a boolean is being passed instead.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery;

trait DiscoveryCachedTrait {

  use DiscoveryTrait;

  /**
   * Cached definitions array.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $definitions;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDefinition($plugin_id, $exception_on_invalid = TRUE) {
    // Fetch definitions if they're not loaded yet.
    if (!isset($this->definitions)) {
      $this->getDefinitions();
    }

    return $this->doGetDefinition($this->definitions, $plugin_id, $exception_on_invalid);
  }

}
```

The signature for the method **doGetDefinition()** from DiscoveryTrait.php file is as following. As mentioned in the comments doc block, it expects **$definitions** to be an array containing the available plugin definitions.

```
/**
* Gets a specific plugin definition.
*
* @param array $definitions
*   An array of the available plugin definitions.
* @param string $plugin_id
*   A plugin id.
* @param bool $exception_on_invalid
*   If TRUE, an invalid plugin ID will cause an exception to be thrown; if
*   FALSE, NULL will be returned.
*
* @return array|null
*   A plugin definition, or NULL if the plugin ID is invalid and
*   $exception_on_invalid is TRUE.
*
* @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
*   Thrown if $plugin_id is invalid and $exception_on_invalid is TRUE.
*/
protected function doGetDefinition(array $definitions, $plugin_id, $exception_on_invalid) {
    // Avoid using a ternary that would create a copy of the array.
    if (isset($definitions[$plugin_id])) {
    return $definitions[$plugin_id];
    }
    elseif (!$exception_on_invalid) {
    return NULL;
    }

    throw new PluginNotFoundException($plugin_id, sprintf('The "%s" plugin does not exist.', $plugin_id));
}
```

My guess is that the **$definitions** array in **DiscoveryCachedTrat.php** is being fetched from cache, and for some reason, its sometimes loading a boolean value instead of an array. We have the issue in two Drupal applications running with same setup. We didn't see this issue on the Drupal application earlier, when it was running in Apache Web Server and using MySQL server for the database.

Has anyone seen this kind of error in their Drupal applications? I did a lot of troubleshooting but couldn't resolve this error. I am ready to provide any more information if needed.

Comment: "The error message is very long so I pasted the first 7 lines" - You can tell so far it is a View which is broken, for example a handler plugin configured does not exist. Most times you find the View name in the stack trace in a line further down.

Comment: The issue appears with different plugins, not just one. So, I think it has something to do with cache. In the example I provided above, it occurs with the plugin 'query' as mentioned in line _#4_

Comment: The `cache_discovery` table has information about plugin definitions. This may or may not be cleared for a specific plugin manager. Truncating the table should be safe, but you probably want to take a back up. The only times I've needed to do this is during development when I really mess up my annotations and I don't feel like uninstalling and re-installing my module.

Comment: Manually clearing all the cache tables didn't help. The issue keeps recurring. I'm thinking more in the way that caches on the MS SQL Server database are getting corrupted time to time. Are there any particular settings that Drupal requires for the cache being stored on the Database?